# Substring from a list of strings

Tags: vb.net, string, function, substring

I have strings:

`string1 = Janko||A12 
 string2 = VHS No||RY3
 string3 = No St bond||40p`

I want to always get the last 3 digits after the character ||. How do I go about this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the `String.IndexOf` and `String.Substring` functions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a total lack of effort to solve the problem asked

Comment: I did try using various ways around it. I used the Substring function with the istr function but to no avail. Also tried using the mid function but didn't get the results I wanted. This was when I decided to post it here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string s1 = "string||23";
var value = s1.Substring(s1.IndexOf("||")+2);
```

[**Demo**](http://dotnetfiddle.net/nkgBlB)